# how to plot the values in a set of key-value pairs with Python

Tags: python, key-value

Using Python I was wondering if there were a faster way to plot the values of A and B without going through the troubles of saving them into 2 different arrays

```
    {'A': 0.7452920360819947, 'B': 0.5692557501718727}
    {'A': 0.7680988343673212, 'B': 0.5495359141383478}
    {'A': 0.7831645842999736, 'B': 0.5346174541475203}
    {'A': 0.7910552458637528, 'B': 0.5262811670299319}
    {'A': 0.7945325379936994, 'B': 0.5223904375178747}
    {'A': 0.7959286672497986, 'B': 0.5207298780860258}
    {'A': 0.7964656379225264, 'B': 0.5200471890029877}
    {'A': 0.7966683078984395, 'B': 0.5197703896938074}
    {'A': 0.7967441494752115, 'B': 0.5196586622041124}
    {'A': 0.7967724046132105, 'B': 0.5196136079148447}
    {'A': 0.7967829009034072, 'B': 0.5195954342272032}
```

Comment: What are you using to plot your points?

Comment: I'm guessing that it's going to be easiest and most efficient to simply parse the data into separate arrays, though there might be a solution I don't know of.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, how the input is exactly given. Anyhow, it's not that much pain to extract two arrays:

```py
import pylab as pl

pairs = [
    {'A': 0.7452920360819947, 'B': 0.5692557501718727},
    {'A': 0.7680988343673212, 'B': 0.5495359141383478},
    {'A': 0.7831645842999736, 'B': 0.5346174541475203},
    {'A': 0.7910552458637528, 'B': 0.5262811670299319},
    {'A': 0.7945325379936994, 'B': 0.5223904375178747},
    {'A': 0.7959286672497986, 'B': 0.5207298780860258},
    {'A': 0.7964656379225264, 'B': 0.5200471890029877},
    {'A': 0.7966683078984395, 'B': 0.5197703896938074},
    {'A': 0.7967441494752115, 'B': 0.5196586622041124},
    {'A': 0.7967724046132105, 'B': 0.5196136079148447},
    {'A': 0.7967829009034072, 'B': 0.5195954342272032},
    ]

pl.plot([p['A'] for p in pairs], [p['B'] for p in pairs], 'r-')
```

Comment: Thanks! This is close to what I was looking for.                        pl.plot([p['A'] for p in pairs])
pl.plot([p['B'] for p in pairs])

Comment: "close to"? You might give more information about what you are trying to do. Otherwise it's hard to guess.